# How to Select 2 Different Names from same table and display them on the Condition

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this Query

```
SELECT NAME_NO
    ,(
        SELECT FNAME || ' ' || LNAME || ' ' || BIRTH_DT || ' ' || ' ' || PHONE
        FROM NAMES
        WHERE NAME_NO = 1
        ) AS "NAME1: NAME, DOB, PHONE"
    ,(
        SELECT FNAME || ' ' || LNAME || ' ' || BIRTH_DT || ' ' || ' ' || PHONE
        FROM NAMES
        WHERE NAME_NO = 2
        ) AS "NAME2: NAME, DOB, PHONE"
    ,
FROM NAMES;
```

I get this error:

```
01427. 00000 -  "single-row subquery returns more than one row"
```

I need multiple records.

What is the best method to solve this?

Comment: `NAME_NO` is PK on `NAMES` ? Is your db MySql or Oracle?

Comment: Please refine your tags to only the DBMS you are using.

Comment: with a schema and some data so we can understand the problem better and give you an answer 
   much faster – Also please read [**How to ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) 
   And [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

this is a great place to start  http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: `||` is not the MySQL syntax for concatenation, so the `mysql` tag is inappropriate. Are you using Oracle or SQL-Server?

Comment: DB is Oracle.It does not have a primary key.

Comment: Please show some sample data and the result you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I have A NameNo in the names table which says which name it is,
Name 1 or Name 2. I need to display 2 columns, One as Name1 and another as Name2 I want to display them in different columns

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
SELECT NAME_NO, FNAME || ' ' || LNAME || ' ' || BIRTH_DT || ' ' || ' ' || PHONE AS "NAME1: NAME, DOB, PHONE"
FROM NAMES
UNION
 SELECT FNAME || ' ' || LNAME || ' ' || BIRTH_DT || ' ' || ' ' || PHONE AS "NAME2: NAME, DOB, PHONE"
FROM NAMES
WHERE NAME_NO = 2
```

or this one:

```
WITH N1 AS  (
        SELECT NAME_NO,FNAME || ' ' || LNAME || ' ' || BIRTH_DT || ' ' || ' ' || PHONE AS "VAL"          
        FROM NAMES          
        WHERE NAME_NO = 1),
     N2 AS (
        SELECT FNAME || ' ' || LNAME || ' ' || BIRTH_DT || ' ' || ' ' || PHONE AS "VAL"          
        FROM NAMES          
        WHERE NAME_NO = 2)
SELECT
    NAME_NO,VAL 
FROM N1,N2;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use PIVOT. Try this

```
Select A "NAME1: NAME, DOB, PHONE" , B "NAME2: NAME, DOB, PHONE" from (SELECT FNAME || ' ' || LNAME || ' ' || BIRTH_DT || ' ' || ' ' || PHONE N, NAME_NO  
        FROM NAMES)
Pivot
(Max(N) for NAME_NO  in (1 as A, 2 as B)
);
```